How Can I Adjust Column Width in a TikZ Vertical Bar Graph?
I've created a vertical bar graph using TikZ. Below is the code:
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    % enlargelimits=0.15,
    width=\columnwidth,
    % ymin=90,
    ylabel={Number of non-redundant filters},
    symbolic x coords={Layer 1, Layer 2, Layer 3, Layer 4, Layer 5},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=8pt,
    legend style={ 
        at={(0.25,1.0)},
        anchor=north,
        legend columns=1,
    },
    % legend to name={mylegend},
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    xticklabel style={rotate=0, font=\footnotesize},
]
\addplot [teal, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(Layer 1, 44) (Layer 2, 78) (Layer 3, 139) (Layer 4, 247) (Layer 5, 227)};
\addplot [orange, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(Layer 1, 40) (Layer 2, 71) (Layer 3, 121) (Layer 4, 206) (Layer 5, 168)};
\addplot [blue, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(Layer 1, 38) (Layer 2, 61) (Layer 3, 108) (Layer 4, 186) (Layer 5, 155)};
\addplot [cyan, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(Layer 1, 38) (Layer 2, 61) (Layer 3, 108) (Layer 4, 184) (Layer 5, 154)};
\addplot [red, fill, opacity=0.7, nodes near coords,every node near coord/.append style={xshift=5pt,yshift=12pt,font=\footnotesize,rotate=90, opacity=1}]coordinates {(Layer 1, 48) (Layer 2, 90) (Layer 3, 166) (Layer 4, 307) (Layer 5, 282)};
\legend{Random search, CHIP \cite{Sui2021CHIPCI}, FPC \cite{chen2022fpc}, SPSRC \cite{sun2024towards}, GEM (Ours)}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \ref{mylegend}
\caption{Non-redundant selected filters with SVGG.}
\label{fig:rank}
\end{figure}

Result:

However, I'm facing an issue with too many columns (5 per category), which causes some columns to be truncated, and the space between each category (Layer 1 vs Layer 2) is too small. How can I set the width of a column to make it smaller and fit them all in the picture?
Additionally, I'd appreciate advice on refactoring this figure to make it more visually appealing. I'm considering converting it to a horizontal bar graph.
Thanks in advance for your help.
